# GC problems when inserting large CSV file with Apache Camel

Tags: java, csv, garbage-collection, apache-camel, large-files

I have a large CSV file containing about 5.2M lines. I want to parse this file and insert the data into a database. I am using apache camel for this.

The route is fairly easy (simplified for this example)

```
from("file:work/customer/").id("customerDataRoute")
.split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming()
.parallelProcessing()
.unmarshal(bindyCustomer)
.split(body())
.process(new CustomerProcessor())
.to("sql:INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_DATA(`FIELD1`,`FIELD2`) VALUES(#,#)");
```

bindyCustomer is a BindyCsvDataFormat for the CSV file and 
CustomerProcessor is a Processor that returns the data of the Bindy Customer object as an array of objects for the SQL insert. The actual object has 39 fields (simplified above).

This works all okay for the first 800.000 to 1.000.000 lines but then it comes to a halt.

I have monitored the camel instance with JVisualVM and the Visual GC plugin and I can see that the old generation fills up and when it reaches maximum the whole system comes to a halt but it does not crash. 
At this point the old generation is full, the Eden space is nearly full and both Survivor spaces are empty (as it can't move anything to the old generation I guess).

So what is wrong here? This looks like a memory leak in the Camel SQL component to me. 
The data is mainly stored in ConcurrentHashMap objects.

When I take out the SQL component the old generation hardly fills at all.

I am using Camel 2.15.1 Will try to use 2.17.1 to see whether that fixes the problem.

Update: I have tried Camel 2.17.1 (same problem) and I have tried to insert the do the inserts in Java using java.sql.Statement.executeUPdate. With this option I managed to insert about 2.6 M rows but then it stopped as well. The funny thing is that I don't get a memory error. It just comes to a halt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I figured out what went wrong here. Basically the reading part was too fast compared to the inserting part. The example was a bit oversimplified as there was a seda queue between the reading and inserting (as I had to do a choice on the content which wasn't shown in the example).
But even without the seda queue it never finished. I realized what was wrong when I killed camel and got a message that there were still several thousand in-flight messages.

So there is no point in doing the reading with parallel processing when the inserting side can't keep up.

```
from("file:work/customer/").id("customerDataRoute")
        .onCompletion().log("Customer data  processing finished").end()
        .log("Processing customer data ${file:name}")
        .split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming() //no more parallel processing
        .choice()
            .when(simple("${body} contains 'HEADER TEXT'")) //strip out the header if it exists
            .log("Skipping first line")
            .endChoice()
        .otherwise()
            .to("seda:processCustomer?size=40&concurrentConsumers=20&blockWhenFull=true")
            .endChoice();


from("seda:processCustomer?size=40&concurrentConsumers=20&blockWhenFull=true")
            .unmarshal(bindyCustomer)
            .split(body())
            .process(new CustomerProcessor()).id("CustomProcessor") //converts one Notification into an array of values for the SQL insert
.to("sql:INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_DATA(`FIELD1`,`FIELD2`) VALUES(#,#)");
```

I defined a size on the SEDA queue (by default it is not limited) and made the calling thread block when the queue is full.

```
seda:processCustomer?size=40&concurrentConsumers=20&blockWhenFull=true
```

The parallel processing is done by using 20 concurrent consumers on the SEDA queue. Please note that for what ever reason you have to specify the queue size when you call the route as well (not only where you define it).

Now the memory consumption is minimal and it inserts the 5 million records without problem.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test your code, however, I did note that your second split statement is not streaming.  I recommend trying that.  If you have too many parallel streams of work the GC could fill up before you release the resources which would lock you up.  The Time the SQL statement takes is probably what is allowing the GC to get too much build up time since you are parallelizing the main processing.

```
from("file:work/customer/").id("customerDataRoute")
    .split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming().parallelProcessing()
        .unmarshal(bindyCustomer)
        .split(body()).streaming() //Add a streaming call here and see what happens
            .process(new CustomerProcessor())
            .to("sql:INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_DATA(`FIELD1`,`FIELD2`) VALUES(#,#)");
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've tried it but it didn't solve the problem. The .unmarchal(bindyCustomer) returns an array with one element only, so the streaming shouldn't have made much of a difference anyway in this case. Can you think of anything else that could be wrong? I will try to do the insert in Java to see whether that fixes the problem.

Comment: Hmm I have some rough guesses.  Would you be able to add id tags to your route and Then open your JConsole to confirm where all the threads are "hung"?

Comment: The route already as an ID (customerDataRoute) or are you referring to something else?

Comment: You can add ids to each component inside of your route.  This way your automatically created mbeans will have that id.  Here is a quick tutorial to help you follow what I am talking about: http://michalwarecki.blogspot.com/2012/08/monitoring-and-managing-apache-camel.html

Comment: I must be missing something in the configuration but no MBeans are created. JConsole is not listing any apache MBeans.

Comment: org.apache.camel -> routes -> groupId.artifactId -> routeId   If you want to see an individual processor:  org.apache.camel -> processors-> groupId.artifactId -> routeId

Comment: The problem is org.apache.camel is not appearing in JConsole!

Comment: Never head of that issue.  It should be enabled by default